# Tomcat 7 hangs randomly and stops responding for no apparent reason

Tags: tomcat

I am using the latest Tomcat 7.039 running as a service on windows server 2008 64.
When I check thread dumps, I don't see any errors. The server has enough cpu and memory resources. I am using Hibernate, spring and Struts.

Tomcat just stops responding to any request, for no apparent reason!

Is this a bug or something to do with  my application code?

I contacted Apache team, but I don't think I will get a reply

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: There are no  errors in log files

Comment: with that amount of description you won't get much from the apache team or the stackoverflow crowd. You'll probably have to eliminate your custom code as much as possible, then try again. Or try other means, but in any case: please give more information than "something doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to check more than one log file. In Tomcat 7 there are at least two that can be found under {your_tomcat_home}/logs.

- catalina.yyyy-MM.dd.log
- localhost.yyyy-MM.dd.log

I found several errors that got logged to localhost log that did not show up in catalina log.